# How are the universal enveloping algebra and PBW-theorem for differential graded Lie algebras defined?

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

Differential graded Lie algebras are defined as graded vector spaces $L=\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ over a field of characteristic zero equipped with a bilinear bracket $[-,-] \colon L_i \otimes L_j \to L_{i+j}$ satisfying the graded antisymmetric and graded Jacobi identity together with a differential $d \colon L_{i} \to L_{j}$ which satisfies the graded Leibniz rule. I want to know how the universal enveloping algebra and PBW-theorem are defined for differential graded Lie algebras? Introducing related papers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: All the definitions work *mutatis mutandis*: you only need to incorporate the Koszul signs for the commutators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will ignore the differential for a moment, and only deal with the grading for now.
The degree of a homogeneous element $x$ will be denoted by $|x|$.

- For any two graded vector spaces $V$ and $W$, the tensor product $V ⊗ W$ inherits a grading from $V$ and $W$ given by
  $$
    |v ⊗ w| = |v| + |w| \,.
  $$
  In other words, we have $(V ⊗ W)_i = \bigoplus_{j + k = i} V_j ⊗ W_k$ for every degree $i$.
  It follows that for every natural exponent $n ≥ 0$ the tensor power $V^{⊗n}$ inherits a grading from $V$ given by
  $$
    |v_1 ⊗ \dotsm ⊗ v_n|
    =
    |v_1| + \dotsb + |v_n| \,.
  $$
  Therefore, the tensor algebra $\mathrm{T}(V) = \bigoplus_{n ≥ 0} V^{⊗ n}$ inherits a grading from $V$.
  This grading makes $\mathrm{T}(V)$ into a graded algebra.
  This ‘graded tensor algebra’ has the expected universal property:
  wherever $A$ is graded algebra, every homomorphism of graded vector spaces from $V$ to $A$ extends uniquely to a homomorphism of graded algebras from $\mathrm{T}(V)$ to $A$.
- Every graded algebra $A$ can be made into a graded Lie algebra via the graded commutator
  $$
    [a, b] = ab - (-1)^{|a| |b|} ba \,.
  $$
- Let $L$ be a graded Lie algebra.
  The *universal enveloping algebra* of $L$ is a graded Lie algebra $\mathrm{U}(L)$ together with a homomorphism of graded Lie algebras $i \colon L \to \mathrm{U}(L)$ satisfying the following universal property:
  for every graded algebra $A$ and every homomorphism of graded Lie algebras $f \colon L \to A$ there exists a unique homomorphism of graded algebras $φ \colon \mathrm{U}(L) \to A$ with $φ ∘ i = f$.
- The universal enveloping algebra of a graded Lie algebra $L$ can be constructed in the usual way.
  We consider the tensor algebra $\mathrm{T}(L)$ and the ideal $I$ of $\mathrm{T}(L)$ generated the elements of the form $[x, y]_{\mathrm{T}(L)} - [x, y]_L$ with $x, y ∈ L$.
  In other words, the ideal $I$ is generated by elements of the form $x ⊗ y - (-1)^{|x| |y|} y ⊗ x - [x, y]_L$ where $x$ and $y$ are homogeneous elements of $L$.
  The ideal $I$ is generated by homogeneous elements and is therefore homogeneous.
  The quotient algebra $\mathrm{U}(L) := \mathrm{T}(L) / I$ therefore inherits a grading from $\mathrm{T}(L)$.
  The composite
  $$
    i \colon L \to \mathrm{T}(L) \to \mathrm{U}(L)
  $$
  is the required homomorphism of graded Lie algebras.
- Let $(x_λ)_{λ ∈ Λ}$ be a vector space basis of $L$ consisting of homogeneous elements, and where $(Λ, ≤)$ linearly ordered.
  The universal enveloping algebra $\mathrm{U}(L)$ has a vector space basis consisting of the ordered monomials
  $$
    x_{λ_1}^{n_1} \dotsm x_{λ_r}^{n_r}
  $$
  with $r ≥ 0$, $λ_1 < \dotsb < λ_r$, $n_i ≥ 1$, and $n_i = 1$ if $x_{λ_i}$ is of odd degree.

The above graded PBW-theorem can be found as part of Theorem 21.1 in *Rational Homotopy Theory* by Felix, Halperin and Thomas.

Suppose now that we are not only dealing with gradings, but also with differentials.
I assume that these gradings are supposed to be degree $-1$, i.e., that $|d(x)| = |x| - 1$ for every homogeneous element $x$.
We can then check that all of the above constructions inherit suitable differentials:

- For any two differential graded vector spaces $V$ and $W$, their tensor products $V ⊗ W$ inherits a differential from $V$ and $W$ given by
  $$
    d(v ⊗ w) = d(v) ⊗ w + (-1)^{|v|} v ⊗ d(w) \,.
  $$
  This differentail makes the graded vector space $V ⊗ W$ into a differential graded vector space.
  It follows that for every natural exponent $n ≥ 0$ the graded vector space $V^{⊗ n}$ becomes a differential graded vector space with differential
  $$
    d(v_1 ⊗ \dotsb ⊗ v_n)
    =
    \sum_{i = 0}^n
    (-1)^{|v_1| + \dotsb + |v_i|}
    v_1 ⊗ \dotsb ⊗ d(v_i) ⊗ \dotsb v_n \,.
  $$
  The resulting differential on the tensor algebra $\mathrm{T}(V) = \bigoplus_{n ≥ 0} V^{⊕ n}$ makes it into a differential graded algebra.
- We have constructed the graded universal enveloping algebra $\mathrm{U}(L)$ as a quotient $\mathrm{T}(L) / I$ for a specific ideal $I$. This ideal satisfies $d(I) ⊆ I$, whence the differential of $\mathrm{T}(L)$ induces a differential on $\mathrm{U}(L)$, making it into a differential graded algebra.
- Every differential graded algebra becomes a differentail graded Lie algebra via the graded commutator.
- The homomorphism of graded Lie algebras $i$ from $L$ to $\mathrm{U}(L)$ is a homomorphism of differential graded Lie algebras, and it satisfies the expected universal property:
  for every differential graded algebra $A$ and every homomorphism of differential graded Lie algebras $f$ from $L$ to $A$, there exists a unique homomorphism of differential graded algebras $φ$ from $\mathrm{U}(L)$ to $A$ with $φ ∘ i = f$.
- The PBW-theorem remains unchanged since it makes no reference to the differential.

Some possible sources:

- Chapter 21 in *Rational Homotopy Theory* by Felix, Halperin, Thomas (Graduate Texts in Mathematics, number 205).
- Appendix B in *Rational Homotopy Theory* by Quillen.
- I once gave a seminar talk about a related topic; the handout of this talk can be found online at https://gitlab.com/cionx/topology-seminar-hopf-algebras-ss19/-/raw/master/handout.pdf.

Comment: Thank you very much for comprehensive answer.